# Why does std::atomic_flag cause a deadlock here?

Tags: c++, concurrency, atomic, c++20

Why does this ping-pong example with C++20 `std::atomic_flag` often result in a deadlock? I am using GCC 11.1 to compile.

```cpp
#include <atomic>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

constexpr auto count_limit = 10'000;

auto atomic_flag = std::atomic_flag{};
auto counter = std::atomic<int>{};

void ping() {
    while (counter < count_limit) {
        atomic_flag.wait(true);

        ++counter;

        atomic_flag.test_and_set();
        atomic_flag.notify_one();
    }
}

void pong() {
    while (counter < count_limit) {
        atomic_flag.wait(false);
        atomic_flag.clear();
        atomic_flag.notify_one();
    }
}

int main() {
    atomic_flag.test_and_set();

    {
        auto const t1 = std::jthread{ping};
        auto const t2 = std::jthread{pong};
    }

    std::cout << "Finished\n";
}
```

Update: The "deadlock" does not occur on the Linux machine on godbolt.org: https://godbolt.org/z/zPb8d1bca. It does not happen on my own Linux machine either. It does happen on my Windows machine, so this might be a GCC bug that is specific to Windows.

Comment: Every time pong will be executed first it will never terminate (more precisely when clear will be executed first), clear set the flag to false and it will never increase the counter, it is not a dead-lock in classical sense.

I more interesting example will be to swap clear with test_and_set position.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean since your comment is phrased rather ambiguously (what does "executed first" mean? In relation to what?). Anyways, I think you misunderstood how wait(false) and wait(true) work. Read here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic_flag/wait

Comment: Maybe changing `notify_one` to `notify_all` fixes the issue? There is [this bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=100334) recently fixed. It is not exactly your scenario but can be the cause because of jthread wait which can internally use the same structures.

Comment: I tried both changing to ``notify_all`` and using ``std::thread`` instead of ``std::jthread``, the behavior persists :^(